# "The type B cannot be a superinterface of C; a superinterface must be an interface" error

Tags: java

Let's assume I got this interface A:

```
interface A
{
    void doThis();
    String doThat();
}
```

So, I want some abstracts classes to implement the method `doThis()` but not the `doThat()` one:

```
abstract class B implements A
{
    public void doThis()
    {
        System.out.println("do this and then "+ doThat());
    }
    
}

abstract class B2 implements A
{
    public void doThis()
    {
        System.out.println(doThat() + "and then do this");
    }
}
```

There error comes when you finally decide to implement de doThat method in a regular class:

```
public class C implements B
{
    public String doThat()
    {
        return "do that";
    }
}
```

This class leads me to the error aforementioned:

> "The type B cannot be a superinterface of C; a superinterface must be an interface"

Anyone could now if this hierarchy of classes is valid or should I do other way round?

Comment: For more details I recommend looking at the Answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implement-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must use `extends`

```
public class C extends B
```

Its important to understand the difference between the `implements` and `extends` Keywords. So, I recommend you start reading at this question: [Implements vs extends: When to use? What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implement-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference) and the answers there.

Comment: Thanks! I also forgot to add the public abstract String doThat() to each abstract classes :S

Comment: @PainyJames you don't need to add the `public abstract String doThat()` to each of the abstract classes.

Answer (score 5):

Since `B` is a class, the correct syntax is to use `extends`:

```
public class C extends B {
```

Answer (score 3):

B is an abstract class and cannot be used with the "implements" keyword. You have to use "extends" instead.