# Meaning of implements when defining a new class

Tags: java, class, implements

I saw this code

```
class BinTree1 implements BinTree{
    Object val;
    BinTree1 left, right;
    // abstr(null) = E
    // abstr (val, left, right) =
    // N((abstr left) val (abstr right))

    public BinTree1 (BinTree1 l, Object o, BinTree1 r){
        val = o;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    public Object val() {
        return val;
    }
```

I wonder what this implements means? I was searching the web, but all I found was something about interfaces...

Comment: When talking about C++ then it means nothing because there is no such thing in C++. What you have there is a piece of *Java* code.

Comment: In C++, it means nothing. In whatever language this is, it probably means that `BinTree` is an interface, and `BinTree1` a class implementing that interface. In C++, you'd do that by inheriting from an abstract class.

Comment: There is no such things in C++. Tag properly.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Also note the public specifiers. Definitively, is Java

Comment: Okay. Funny outcome. Then this will be the problem. :D Thanks!

Comment: Two upvotes? Seriously?

Comment: @Manu343726 And why the downvotes? The OP clearly didn't know this wasn't C++ code, so what?

Comment: Why stop searching when you got to _something about interfaces_? Delving a little deeper would at a minimum let you know it's not C++, or at best would introduce a new realm of programming in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is already stated in the comments: this is probably java code.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implement-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference) which explains the "implements" keyword and also the difference to the "extends" keyword which is corresponding to c++ inheritance. (You tagged your answer with c++ so I assume you know inheritance in c++ and were confused about the keyword.)