# What are the conditions for Serializable?

Tags: java, serializable

Suppose I have a java class, `MyClass`, that is not inherited from any class. `MyClass` implements `Serializable`.

Can `MyClass` be `Serializable` with no other conditions?
Does it depend on what objects `MyClass` contain, and if these objects are `Serializable` themselves?

For example in the class below, if `Mappedoodle2` does not implement `Serializable`, will I get an exception when  `Mappedoodle` is serialized?

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Mappedoodle implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1760231235147491826L;
   private String text;
   private int value;
   private Mappedoodle2 mm = new Mappedoodle2();

   public Mappedoodle(String text, int value) {           
       this.text = text;
       this.value = value;
   }

   public String getText() {
       return text;
   }

   public int getValue() {
       return value;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return text + ", " + value;
   }

}
```

Comment: Alot of these questions are already answered. So I'll just refer you to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference

Comment: Remember that an interface is an agreement that you're making when using it that you will define the provided methods.

Comment: FirebladeDan : I'm not asking about differnt between inherits and implements. I asked if objects in Serializable class must them self implement Serializable interface

Comment: Are you saying MyClass objects? or other Objects that can live in MyClass? This serializable idea is just a marker. You can serialize any object into bytes just need the marker..

Comment: MyClass  holds (contain)  other objects : String , Integer , List and some other self defined objects (MyClass1 , MyClass2 ...). All these objects has to implements Serializable too (beside of MyClass  ) ?

Comment: Child classes do need to be serializable calling classes do not.

Comment: Yes you do! You must define `mm` transient, or make it class serializable.

Answer (score 1):

To serialize the object, I'm assuming you are using an `ObjectOutputStream`. Here's some relevant documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)

That section describes the basics of how objects are written. The stream writes the following:

- The class that the object is
- The signature (`public class Mappedoodle implements Serializable`)
- All fields that are neither `transient` nor `static`

Each field that is an object will also be written to the stream. This means that each field must implement `Serializable`. If it doesn't, you will get a `NotSerializableException`.

You have a couple of options for making this work:

- Make `Mappedoodle2` serializable
- Make the field `mm` `transient`, which just means it won't be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

First, all classes technically extend from `java.lang.Object`, so even `MyClass` will inherit from it.

`MyClass` can implement `Serializable` just by implementing the interface, like any other interface.  If a class contains properties of a class that implements `Serializable`, the parent class need not implement `Serializable` itself.