# Error when implementing interfaces with greenDAO

Tags: java, android, greendao, implements

I'm trying to use greenDAO's `implementsInterface` method, here is most of my main generator class:

```
private static void addTables(final Schema schema) {
    Entity photo_pronoun = addCard(schema);
    Entity simple_pronoun = addSimpleCard(schema);
    Entity original_pronoun = addOriginalCard(schema);

    //implementsInterface method
    original_pronoun.implementsInterface("addNewCard");
    simple_pronoun.implementsInterface("addNewCard");
}

private static Entity addCard(final Schema schema) {
    Entity card = schema.addEntity("addNewCard");
    card.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
    card.addStringProperty("cardName").notNull();
    card.addStringProperty("cardSpeech");
    card.addByteArrayProperty("cardIcon");

    return card;
}
private static Entity addSimpleCard(final Schema schema) {
    Entity card = schema.addEntity("addSimpleCard");
    card.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
    card.addStringProperty("cardName").notNull();
    card.addStringProperty("cardSpeech");
    card.addByteArrayProperty("cardIcon");
    return card;
}

private static Entity addOriginalCard(final Schema schema) {
    Entity card = schema.addEntity("addOriginalCard");
    card.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
    card.addStringProperty("cardName").notNull();
    card.addStringProperty("cardSpeech");
    card.addByteArrayProperty("cardIcon");
    return card;
}
```

When I run this to create my files I get an error in original_pronoun and in simple_pronoun on my first line at `addNewCard`:

> interface expected here
>   `public class addOriginalCard implements addNewCard {`

I get that error because its not an interface, but I'm confused on how to fix it. The `implementsInterface` method says it takes a string but I've tried this and the database name with no joy. Can anyone tell me what I need to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a greenDAO problem: `addNewCard` is a class, not an interface. If your model class needs to inherit from another class, you have to use `setSuperclass()` method. Example:

```
original_pronoun.setSuperclass("addNewCard");
```

Note that greenDAO doesn't support another entity as a super class yet, if this is your intention.

Check [greenDAO docs for Inheritance and Interfaces](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities#Inheritance_Interfaces_and_Serializable).
See also this question: [Implements vs. Extends. When to use? What's the Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference)

Comment: sorry i should have been clearer i know this isnt a greendao error,

Comment: @MartinSeal Sorry if I seemed rude, this was not the intention. :D

Comment: not at all, i took on board your comments read the docs again ive researched what you said about implements and extends and looked at abstract classes but i am still completely baffled about how im going to move forward with this, but i appreciate your comments