# extends AppCompatActivity and LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, extends, appcompatactivity

there's a way to extends AppCompatActivity and LinearLayout?

when I do this , it's full of error

```
public class MessageContainerView extends AppCompatActivity,LinearLayout implements OnLayoutChangedListener, OnCreateContextMenuListener,OnClickListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Java basic :

A class can only extend one other class. A class can implement several interfaces.

Please refer the following link
[Implements vs extends: When to use? What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend either AppCompatActivity or LinearLayout, but not both. Java does not allow to multiple inheritance

Answer (score 0):

you cannot extends multiple class in a single class because android is java based and java cannot support multiple inheritances using the class.So you can only one class extends at a time