# How does multiple Interface inheritance works in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core 2` and a question came to my mind. How does `Interface` instance gives difference implementations?

Lets get `IServiceCollection`. It has various methods like `AddMvc(), AddDbContext<T>()` etc. Checking the **source code** `IServiceCollection` doesn't have any methods that has to be implemented if someone implements it. It simply inherits `IList<ServiceDescriptor>` and the inheritance chain of `IList < ICollection < IEnumerable`

Ok, went to see `ServiceDescriptor` but the class **doesn't** implement any `interface` and in it there is no method implementations like `AddMvc(), AddDbContext<T>`

Then how and from where do these methods come from ?
How it works behind the scenes?

I'm really trying to learn OOP, but I think I miss some basics.

Comment: The question in your first paragraph has a flawed premise.  Interfaces don't give implementations.  That's what classes do.

Comment: AddMvc() and AddDbContext are extensions method of the IServiceCollection interface

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, so the answer to the question in your title is: it doesn't.  Classes implement interfaces, they don't inherit them.  Classes inherit from other classes.  A class can implement a hundred interfaces, but it can only inherit from a single class.

Comment: The 'multiple interface inheritance' misconception is a common one - unfortunately C# uses the same syntax for implementing an interface, as it does for inheriting a class, viz `X : Y`. [Java makes the distinction clearer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10839131/314291) with the different keywords `extends` and `implements`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that interfaces can have extra methods tacked on.  In C# we do this using [*extension methods*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).  Here is a basic example:

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    int GetFoo();
}

public class Foo : IFoo 
{
    public int GetFoo()
    {
        var foo = ... // does something to get a foo
        return foo;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IFoo theFoo = new Foo();
        theFoo.PityTheFoo();       // wait, what?  
    }
}
```

Now at this point I can hear you saying "Amy!  Hold on! `IFoo` doesn't have a method that does any kind of pitying!"  And you would be right.  Pretend for a moment that you don't own the source code for `IFoo`.  How can you add a method to `IFoo`?  Or, suppose you *do* own the source for `IFoo`, and want to add a method without having to modify every class that implements that interface?

This is where extension methods come in:

```
public static class FooExtensions 
{
    public static void PityTheFoo(this IFoo foo)
    {
        // pities the foo
    }
}
```

Note the `this` keyword inside the function declaration.  That indicates this is an extension method.  It tacks our `PityTheFoo` method onto the interface.  Classes that implement the `IFoo` interface do not need to implement `PityTheFoo()`.  If you had one hundred different `Foo` classes, all implementing this interface, *none* of them will require modification.

Extension methods aren't part of the inheritance chain.  When the compiler reaches the commented line in `Program`, this is what it "pretends" the code looks like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IFoo theFoo = new Foo();
        FooExtensions.PityTheFoo(theFoo);
    }
}
```

Why would we want this?

- You don't own the interface, but want to add operations to it.
- You own the interface, but the numerous classes that implement that interface can share the same implementation, sort of like they inherited it.
- The interface might be part of a library.  If you add a method to it, people who use your library will find their code broken until they add the method to their classes.  Extension methods let you avoid the breaking change.

Comment: Perfect explanation, now I get.

Answer (score 0):

`AddMvc()`, `AddDbContext()` etc are **Extension Methods**: a different syntax for invoking a `static` function defined in a totally different class that has the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute` (aka `[Extension]`) applied to it (in C#, an extension method can be written by putting the `this` modifier before the first parameter.

If you use the "Go to definition" feature in VS for those methods you'll see they're defined on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addmvc?view=aspnetcore-2.0