# How to inherit a method in Java from an A class to a C class

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, call

I have three classes. Class A is titled `Circle`. Class B is titled `ColorfulCircle`. Class C is titled `ColorfulBouncingCircle`. I need to inherit the methods public double getCenterY(), public double getCenterX, and public void setCenterCoordinates(double centerX, double centerY) from Class “A” Circle so that I can use them in Class “C” ColorfulBouncingCircle.

Circle looks like this:

```
class Circle {

    private double centerX, centerY;

    public double getCenterX() {
        return centerX;
    }

    public double getCenterY() {
        return centerY;
    }

    public void setCenterCoordinates(double centerX, double centerY) {
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }
}
```

There are the exact methods I need to be able to use in `ColorfulBouncingCircle` so that I can use the `centerX` and `centerY` variables in code over there.

I just need to know exactly what do I type in to the `ColorfulBouncingCircle` class so that I can use them.

Thank you.

Comment: You can just use `extends` keyword to inherit your parent class. `class ColorfulBouncingCircle extends Circle { }` that's it! `ColorfulBouncingCircle cbCircle = new ColorfulBouncingCircle(); cbCircle.setCenterCoordinates(123, 321);`

Comment: Have a look at the detail explanation on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference

Comment: that is basic concept of inheritance. go through about inheritance in java. I recommend https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `Circle` class from `ColorfulBouncingCircle` class.

```
public class ColorfulBouncingCircle extends Circle {

}
```

You can then call `getCenterX()`, `getCenterY()` and `setCenterCoordinates()` from the object of `ColorfulBouncingCircle` class.