# Avoid using extends and implements in my class

Tags: java, python, pyjnius

I am brand new to Java and need to use one of the following class definitions in my project.

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
public class ScannerFragment extends Fragment implements myclass {

... ... ...

}
```

Or:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements myclass {

... ... ...

}
```

However, I cannot seem to understand how to implement the `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` as I dont have any gradle.properties file. I am using Pyjnius that allows me to use Java in my Python project.

So my question is: Is there a way to avoid using `Fragment` or `AppCompatActivity` in my code and implement the class `myclass` in another way? I dont understand the `extend` and `implements` method.

Comment: Do you know about the existance of `Types` and `Interfaces` in Python? If so, then in Java you can only `extend a class` single one per inheritor, and `implement an interface` multiple at a time....

Comment: So the hint here is: 1) *If it is defined as `class` you can only extend by using `extends`* (should implement all abstract methods) 2) *If it is defined as `interface` then you can only `implemennts` it* (should implement all abstract methods)....

Comment: You don't have to implement Frame. This should answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extends means you want to derive a subclass from an existing class. Implements means you will implement an interface.