# Why Enum classes can't be extended?

Tags: java, enums

Please, help me understand why enum classes can't be extended.
This code:
`

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(B.C);
    }
    
    public enum A {
        A, B, C
    }
    
    public enum B extends A {
        C, D, E
    }
}
```

`
Will produce compile exception:

```
error: '{' expected
    public enum B extends A {
                 ^
```

But why? Is enum class isn't regular class?

But enum can implement interfaces... In my mind the only option why this code don't compile is that emun classes are final, is it true?

Comment: They're final, and they each already have a class they extend *directly*: `java.lang.Enum`

Comment: It doesn't compile because the language is designed this way. What would `enum B extends A` *mean*? Please see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585), and clarify what you mean by "why".

Comment: @ernest_k Not necessarily though. They are not final if the enum constants have class bodies.

Comment: Think it's the same subject as here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414755/7563004

Comment: See also the difference between `extends` and `implements` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839155/7563004